# Get meta information from the database with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm probably missing something simple here but how do I get the primary key for a table using Laravel/Eloquent? When I execute the following I'm getting an Incorrect Syntax error while it works when executing directly on the database.

```
$primarykey = DB::table('table')->whereRaw('SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY"')->get();
```

Comment: to debug your query, instead of `->get()` do `->toSql()` and you will see how `whereRaw()` works and replace it with `selectRaw()`

Comment: Your query translates to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY"`. You might need to use `DB::select('SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY"')` instead

Comment: @apokryfos this solution worked for me, be aware you have to pass an array as the second argument or it will throw an error ```DB::select('SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY"', []);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with following code and it worked.

```
$primarykey = DB::select('SHOW KEYS FROM users WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY"');
```

I had used select of DB without get method because it returns array like this

```
[
     {#3558
       +"Table": "users",
       +"Non_unique": 0,
       +"Key_name": "PRIMARY",
       +"Seq_in_index": 1,
       +"Column_name": "id",
       +"Collation": "A",
       +"Cardinality": 1,
       +"Sub_part": null,
       +"Packed": null,
       +"Null": "",
       +"Index_type": "BTREE",
       +"Comment": "",
       +"Index_comment": "",
     },
   ]
```

So please try and let me know if you find any issue in it.
Thanks